# What are "indirect-X" after zpool remove?

Tags: zfs, zpool

After `zpool remove`, the removed disks are shown as `indirect-0`, `indirect-1`, `indirect-2`, and so forth.

- What are they?
- How can I get rid of them?
- Will they pose any problems?

**Demonstrate:**

There were two disks. One of them is removed. Then a new disk is added back into the pool.

```
# truncate -s 1G raid{0,1}_{1..4}.img
# ls /tmp/test_zfs_remove/
raid0_1.img  raid0_2.img  raid0_3.img  raid0_4.img  raid1_1.img  raid1_2.img  raid1_3.img  raid1_4.img

# zpool create jbod /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_{1,2}.img
# zpool status -v ; zpool list -v
  pool: jbod
 state: ONLINE
config:

        NAME                                STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        jbod                                ONLINE       0     0     0
          /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_1.img  ONLINE       0     0     0
          /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_2.img  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
NAME                                 SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
jbod                                1.88G   110K  1.87G        -         -     0%     0%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
  /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_1.img   960M    54K   960M        -         -     0%  0.00%      -    ONLINE
  /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_2.img   960M  55.5K   960M        -         -     0%  0.00%      -    ONLINE
```

Now we `zpool remove` disk 2. Please note **indirect-1 shows up**.

```
# zpool remove jbod /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_2.img
# zpool status -v ; zpool list -v
  pool: jbod
 state: ONLINE
remove: Removal of vdev 1 copied 49.5K in 0h0m, completed on Fri Jun 10 02:03:59 2022
        144 memory used for removed device mappings
config:

        NAME                                STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        jbod                                ONLINE       0     0     0
          /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_1.img  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
NAME                                 SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
jbod                                 960M   148K   960M        -         -     0%     0%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
  /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_1.img   960M   148K   960M        -         -     0%  0.01%      -    ONLINE
  indirect-1                            -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
```

Then we `zpool add` disk 3. **indirect-1 does not go away**.

```
# zpool add jbod /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_3.img
# zpool status -v ; zpool list -v
  pool: jbod
 state: ONLINE
remove: Removal of vdev 1 copied 49.5K in 0h0m, completed on Fri Jun 10 02:03:59 2022
        144 memory used for removed device mappings
config:

        NAME                                STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        jbod                                ONLINE       0     0     0
          /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_1.img  ONLINE       0     0     0
          /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_3.img  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
NAME                                 SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
jbod                                1.88G   222K  1.87G        -         -     0%     0%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
  /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_1.img   960M   222K   960M        -         -     0%  0.02%      -    ONLINE
  indirect-1                            -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
  /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_3.img   960M      0   960M        -         -     0%  0.00%      -    ONLINE
```

Even if we `zpool remove` disk 3, then `zpool add` disk 3 (the same disk) immediately, another **indirect-2 shows up too**.

```
# zpool remove jbod /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_3.img
# zpool add jbod /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_3.img
# zpool status -v ; zpool list -v
  pool: jbod
 state: ONLINE
remove: Removal of vdev 2 copied 11.5K in 0h0m, completed on Fri Jun 10 02:09:35 2022
        240 memory used for removed device mappings
config:

        NAME                                STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        jbod                                ONLINE       0     0     0
          /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_1.img  ONLINE       0     0     0
          /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_3.img  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
NAME                                 SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
jbod                                1.88G   279K  1.87G        -         -     0%     0%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
  /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_1.img   960M   260K   960M        -         -     0%  0.02%      -    ONLINE
  indirect-1                            -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
  indirect-2                            -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
  /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_3.img   960M  18.5K   960M        -         -     0%  0.00%      -    ONLINE
```

What make things more worrying is that, if a disk is degraded (simulated by `zpool offline -f`), **the degraded status does not go away**.

```
# zpool add jbod /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_4.img
# zpool offline -f jbod /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_4.img
# zpool remove jbod /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_4.img
# zpool status -v ; zpool list -v
  pool: jbod
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices has experienced an unrecoverable error.  An
        attempt was made to correct the error.  Applications are unaffected.
action: Determine if the device needs to be replaced, and clear the errors
        using 'zpool clear' or replace the device with 'zpool replace'.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-9P
remove: Removal of vdev 4 copied 19K in 0h0m, completed on Fri Jun 10 02:16:49 2022
        336 memory used for removed device mappings
config:

        NAME                                STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        jbod                                DEGRADED     0     0     0
          /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_1.img  ONLINE       0     0     0
          /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_3.img  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
NAME                                 SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
jbod                                1.88G   308K  1.87G        -         -     0%     0%  1.00x  DEGRADED  -
  /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_1.img   960M   154K   960M        -         -     0%  0.01%      -    ONLINE
  indirect-1                            -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
  indirect-2                            -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
  /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid0_3.img   960M   154K   960M        -         -     0%  0.01%      -    ONLINE
  indirect-4                            -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -  DEGRADED
```

Side Note:

- If a disk was not degraded, `zpool remove` will **not** cause data loss. Although this is a RAID0 JBOD setup without redundancy, data will be copied to the remaining disks when the `zpool remove` command is issued. If the remaining disks do not have enough space to accommodate all the data, "cannot remove (disk): out of space" error is prompted. Then we cannot `zpool remove` a disk.
- Using `zpool replace` (rather than `zpool remove` then `zpool add`) will not generate the weird **indirect-X** things. But it has some drawbacks. The new disk must be equal to or larger than the replaced disk. On the contrary, we can `zpool remove` a larger disk, then `zpool add` a smaller disk.

One more side demonstration that `zpool detach` then `zpool attach` **mirrors will not produce the weird indirect-X things**.

```
# zpool destroy jbod
# zpool create mirr mirror /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_1.img /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_2.img
# zpool detach mirr /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_2.img
# zpool attach mirr /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_1.img /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_3.img
# zpool detach mirr /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_3.img
# zpool attach mirr /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_1.img /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_3.img
# zpool attach mirr /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_1.img /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_4.img
# zpool offline -f mirr /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_4.img
# zpool status -v ; zpool list -v
  pool: mirr
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to persistent errors.
        Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue functioning in a
        degraded state.
action: Replace the faulted device, or use 'zpool clear' to mark the device
        repaired.
  scan: resilvered 291K in 00:00:00 with 0 errors on Fri Jun 10 02:47:06 2022
config:

        NAME                                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        mirr                                  DEGRADED     0     0     0
          mirror-0                            DEGRADED     0     0     0
            /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_1.img  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_3.img  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_4.img  FAULTED      0     0     0  external device fault

errors: No known data errors
NAME                                   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
mirr                                   960M   200K   960M        -         -     0%     0%  1.00x  DEGRADED  -
  mirror-0                             960M   200K   960M        -         -     0%  0.02%      -  DEGRADED
    /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_1.img      -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
    /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_3.img      -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
    /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_4.img      -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -   FAULTED

# zpool detach mirr /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_4.img
# zpool status -v ; zpool list -v
  pool: mirr
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 291K in 00:00:00 with 0 errors on Fri Jun 10 02:47:06 2022
config:

        NAME                                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        mirr                                  ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                            ONLINE       0     0     0
            /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_1.img  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_3.img  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
NAME                                   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
mirr                                   960M   196K   960M        -         -     0%     0%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
  mirror-0                             960M   196K   960M        -         -     0%  0.01%      -    ONLINE
    /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_1.img      -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
    /tmp/test_zfs_remove/raid1_3.img      -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
```

Comment: zpool features `device_removal` and `obsolete_counts` may give some insight on this issue. https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/7/zpool-features.7.html

Comment: I am not an experienced sysadmin by any means but reading the description of both of these does not seem to answer your own questions. I had to remove a defective disk lately and tried to add a few spare external SSDs to prevent the pool from going over 95% usage, and removed part of them, and now I have 5 of these `indirect-X` things that I have no idea how to remove. Any direct response on how do we remove them?